# Chrome new tab holds memory

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm developing a Chat on nodejs. Like any chat , users sends links all the time. The situation is whenever a user click on any link (anchor tag with '_blank' target) , Chrome open a new tab (Example: a youtube video) that seems to link both , main and new tab , in memory looking like this :

[image: http://s22.postimg.org/a9u5sm9dt/Chat_Tabs.png]

It seems like a normal behavior but when the user close that new tab , main tab holds memory from newer tab , reducing just a few Ks.

[image: http://s22.postimg.org/e7m0vrlkx/Chat_Tabs_User_Close.png]

Garbage Collector doesn't run always and supposing that an user open 30 links , memory can grow significantly.

Anyone know how to create an anchor tag that can avoid this behavior?
It's a Chrome problem ? My version is 33.0

An interesting behavior is when the user does a right-click and open a new tab from the menu. Chrome creates a new tab separately. That's the behavior I want to replicate.

Cheers!

Comment: There is nothing you can do, as far as server-side or client-executed code, to manipulate or affect garbage collection or memory use of the user agent.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I know that, but an interesting behavior is when the user do a right-click and open a new tab from it. Chrome creates a new tab separately and that is what I want to replicate.

Comment: Apparently this is a known frustration and looks like every browser has issues here or there with it: https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+memory+leak

Comment: Also when you say my main tab holds memory - are you sure you aren't allocating any kind of javascript objects etc. that are in a data structure that's preventing GC?  You sure it's not just your own memory leak?

Comment: @DrLivingston I found a solution , setting **rel=noreferrer** in the anchor tag. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @machinerium You should add that as an answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to this, setting **rel=noreferrer** to the anchor tag. Now it opens any number of tabs separately without overloading memory on main tab.